# RXJS emit immediately and retry

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

We are making an http request in Angular that returns some data containing a boolean that indicates whether or not the data has been completely processed. We would like to emit the incomplete data from the first http response and continue making http requests until processed is true. We also would like to avoid making duplicate http requests if the first response returns with processed true. We are using the retryBackoff library, which if I understand correctly is just retryWhen with a delay under the hood.

Here's a sample from the code we're working on:

```
const crashDetails$ = combineLatest(crashId$, database$)
   .pipe(switchMap(([crashId, database]) => { 
        return this._crashDetailsService.getCrashDetails({crashId, database});
    });

const crashDetailsWithRetry$ = crashDetails$
    .pipe(
        tap(crashDetails => {
            if (!crashDetails.processed) {
               throw new Error('Still processing, retry if able');
            }
        }),
        retryBackoff(retryOptions)
    );

return merge($crashDetails, crashDetailsWithRetry$);
```

The problem is 2 requests get made in the case processed is true.

I tried adding share() and shareReplay(1) to crashDetails$, but this causes crashDetailsWithRetry$ to stop working. Is there an easy way to achieve what we want, or should I create a new subject and custom retry logic to handle this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just a conditional polling scheme:

```
 const crashDetails$ = combineLatest(crashId$, database$)
   .pipe(switchMap(([crashId, database]) => { 
        // switch into a timer that switches into your observable, take while processing
        return timer(0, 3000).pipe( // set 3000 to whatever ms interval you want to poll on
          switchMap(() => this._crashDetailsService.getCrashDetails({crashId, database}),
          takeWhile(details => !details.processed, true) //take while not processed
        );
    });

 return crashDetails$;
```

Comment: Will this emit every time we poll the API? the goal is to emit the unprocessed result each poll and finally the processed result at the end thus concluding the polling loop

Comment: yes, it emits every call so long as it completes within the interval, you could use `mergeMapTo` instead to guarantee they all emit regardless of how long they take

Comment: thanks, this got me to the right spot. note the solution requires rxjs v6.4+ and the inclusive flag. we also ended up using intervalBackoff instead of timer an exponential delay between requests. https://codesandbox.io/s/njguf

Comment: True, forgot the inclusive part as that’s new. Glad it helped. You could also achieve a back off effect by adding in the delayWhen operator